# Is there a way to swap 2 structs?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, c++17, swap

In c++ you can swap 2 numbers without 3rd variable:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 5;
x ^= y; 
y ^= x; 
x ^= y; //x = 5, y = 10
```

So I wonder if there is a similar way to swap 2 structs without 3rd variable:

```
struct Position{int x, y;};
int main()
{
   Position firstPose{x = 10, y = 5;};
   Position secPose{x = 5, y = 10;};
   //Now I want to swap firstPose with secPose.
}
```

Is this possible? if so; how to do it

Comment: Not in the general case. If you mean "without manually creating a temporary variable" the aptly named `std::swap` might help.

Comment: You're aware that the xor trick is less efficient?

Comment: swapping two variables with XOR is not specific to C++, it is maths.

Comment: It is technically impossible to swap two structs of size greater than the size of the greatest register without using some intermediate registers (at least you need to read and write to memory piece by piece). Unless there's a specific machine instruction for that, which I'm not aware of. For structs of size at most the size of greatest register you can simply reinterpret it and do the same swap as for ints.

Comment: @molbdnilo I didn't know that

Comment: `swap(firstpose.x, secPose.x); swap(firstpose.y, secPose.y);`?

Comment: it's a very bad idea to use xor swap nowadays. The most obvious reason is the lack of readability, and there are others that you can read in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice

Comment: @MohammedThaier: The difference in efficiency is huge. In a modern CPU, a normal swap is essentially free (happens instantly). This is possible because of "register renaming" - swapping the contents of two registers is done by swapping the register names, not their actual bits. A C++ compiler might pull a very similar trick, and just swap the addresses it uses for `x` and `y`. But the math takes three real operations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no a standard way to swap two structure without an intermediate copy. Arguably, one of the main benefit of swap "is" the intermediate copy, this wonderful article explain how swap is a crucial part to achieve "strong exception guarantee". https://www.stroustrup.com/except.pdf

Furthermore, if the goal is to not make a copy of the struct (because is resource intensive) you can design your class using the pimpl idiom and swap just the pointer (you will still have a third variable but it will be just the raw pointer to the structure).

**If you want to use C++ effectively make yourself familiar with exception safety, it is truly of of the area where the language gives its best**

A bit old but still good article: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/008.htm

At the end, the final solution is create a custom swap function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Position{int x, y;};

void swap(Position& a, Position& b)
{
    a.x ^= b.x; 
    b.x ^= a.x; 
    a.x ^= b.x;

    a.y ^= b.y; 
    b.y ^= a.y; 
    a.y ^= b.y; 
}

int main()
{
    Position a = { 10, 100};
    Position b = { 20, 200};
  
    swap(a, b);
    std::cout << "a:" << a.x << "," << a.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b:" << b.x << "," << b.y << std::endl;
}
```

IMHO, the last option is more for personal amusement than real production code.

Comment: Maybe you could also [mention](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) that *"The expected way to make a program-defined type swappable is to provide a non-member function swap in the same namespace as the type: see [Swappable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Swappable) for details."* and the `using std::swap; swap(t, u);` "trick";

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are some ways to achieve your requirement. But, note that the XOR method of swapping between two values is quite inefficient.

First of all, let's assume the required struct:

```
struct position {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

---

### Method 1

Create your own `swap()` function:

```
void swap(position &pos1, position &pos2) {
    // Swapping X
    verify_overflow(pos1.x, pos2.x); // See about this below
    pos1.x = pos1.x + pos2.x;
    pos2.x = pos1.x - pos2.x;
    pos1.x = pos1.x - pos2.x;

    // Swapping Y
    verify_overflow(pos1.y, pos2.y); // See about this below
    pos1.y = pos1.y + pos2.y;
    pos2.y = pos1.y - pos2.y;
    pos1.y = pos1.y - pos2.y;
}
```

Now, you can implement it like this:

```
swap(v1, v2);
```

**Note:** To prevent undefined-behavior due to the overflows, the following subroutine could be used:

```
inline void verify_overflow(signed int si_a, signed int si_b) {
    signed int sum;

    if (__builtin_sadd_overflow(si_a, si_b, &sum)) {
        std::cerr << "[error] Overflow is possible to happen.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

For example, when you set a struct:

```
position v1 = {2147483647, 2147483644};
```

The program will yield the following error, then UB won't occur:

```
[error] Overflow is possible to happen.
```

---

### Method 2

There is already a built-in `std::swap()` in C++ standard. Its benefit is that you won't need to keep changing the code when the struct alters. The code should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct position {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main(void) {
    position v1 = {5, 10};
    position v2 = {10, 5};

    std::swap(v1, v2);

    std::cout << v1.x << ' ' << v1.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << v2.x << ' ' << v2.y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why std::swap has implementation like in first method? How can this be implemented for a custom structure?

Comment: @dasfex That's why I mentioned *Create your own `swap()`* – in the current situation, that custom `swap()` solves the OP's problem. It needs to be altered when the struct changes.

Comment: Sorry. The phrase "implementation in the code is exactly as the first method" is misleading.

Comment: Using `+` with **signed** `int` for swap might lead to overflow, and so UB.

Comment: @dasfex Now it shouldn't mislead. **Answer Edited.**

Comment: @Jarod42 I've added a subroutine that verifies if an overflow is possible to prevent the undefined-behavior. Check this out.

Comment: So you have a swap which doesn't work for any numbers... :-/ I don't see the bonus to use summations instead of xor. You "just" want to swap each member, not reimplementing swap for integer.

Comment: @Jarod42 What do you mean by – *So you have a swap which doesn't work for any numbers*. Also, I would prevent the XOR method since it's less efficient. Lastly, what else requires to be fixed?

Comment: Your swap now exits instead of UB when overflow would occurs. I expect to be able to swap any numbers. I prefer slow working code, than fast failing code.

Comment: @Jarod42 Well, I'm not interested to slow down the program. The answer for the XOR method is already described in the accepted answer. I'm not going to repeat that answer.